# Отображение разделов меню аккордеона

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть меню аккордеон, в котором все разделы скрыты. При нажатии на заголовок они  открываются. Как доделать так, чтобы 1 раздел был всегда открыт, но при нажатии тоже закрывался?

JS:

```
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Настройка элементов</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Настройка текста</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>3</dd>

    <dt>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Настройка текста</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>4</dd>
</dl>
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/whe6vnto/).

Answer (score 1):

Как простой вариант, можно проверять, виден ли блок. Если при клике блок не был виден, то показывать его:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    $('.accordion > dt > a').on("click", function() {
        var $block = $(this).parent().next();
        var visible = $block.is(':visible');
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if (!visible) {
            $block.slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
    font: 16px Sans-Serif;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius:11px;
    margin-top:0;
}
* .accordion dt, .accordion dd {
    padding: 10px;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.accordion dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.accordion dt:last-of-type, .accordion dd:last-of-type {
    /* border-bottom: 3px solid black;*/
}
.accordion dt a, .accordion dd a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.accordion dd {
    border-top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.accordion dd:last-of-type {
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt>
        <a href="">Настройка элементов</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
    </dd>
    
    <dt>
        <a href="">Настройка текста</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>3</dd>
    
    <dt>
        <a href="">Настройка текста</a>
    </dt>
    <dd>4</dd>
</dl>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если фраза "чтобы 1 раздел был всегда открыт" означает "первый раздел", а не "один раздел", то так:

```
  (function ($) {

        var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

        $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function () {
            allPanels.slideUp();
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

            return false;
        });

    })(jQuery); 

$('.accordion > dd').first().show(); //магия
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd:not(:eq(0))').hide();    
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function () {
        allPanels.not(this).slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().stop().slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

И "javascript:void(0);" - там абсолютно не нужен